# "Error: Could not resolve com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15 when configuring Android project in Flutter"

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, build.gradle

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter project when trying to build the Android part. I've provided the relevant sections of my `build.gradle` files below for reference.

**Android app-level build.gradle (android/app/build.gradle):**

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
/*
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
*/

android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_firebase_crud_operations"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_firebase_crud_operations"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    /*
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    */
}
```

**Project-level build.gradle (android/build.gradle):**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // Apply the Google services Gradle plugin with version
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'
        //version '4.3.15' apply false
        /*
        // Apply the Google services Gradle plugin with version
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
        // version '4.3.15' apply false
        // id 'com.google.gms.google-services'version '4.3.15' apply false
        */
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm receiving the following error message when I try to build the project:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on 22120RN86G in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.
     Required by:
         project :
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have verified that the Firebase BOM version (`32.3.1`) in the app-level `build.gradle` file matches the `com.google.gms.google-services` plugin version (`4.3.15`) in the project-level `build.gradle` file.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?